# How do I strip the \n in a text in a file and then count the words of the text that have more than n letters in python?

Tags: python, count, strip

I need some help with my python homework. I want to count all the words that have more than 14 characters in a text in a file. I first have to strip the \n after each word. This is my Code:

```
b = open("sowpods.txt")
text = b.read()
text.strip("\n")
i = 0
for row in text:
    n = len(row)
    while(n > 14):
        i += 1
print(i)

b.close()
```

It does not work. The output is always 1.

Comment: Why do you want to use python for this? Sed or awk would be much easier

Comment: b.read() will create one line, strip only removes '\n' at the end.  so your for loop only iterates once

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative:

```py
from pathlib import Path
from collections import Counter

sowpods = Path('sowpods.txt')

with sowpods.open() as f:
    words = f.read()
    counter = Counter([word for word in words.split() if len(word) > 14])
    print(counter)
```

That will give you the number of occurrences of every word whose length is greater than 14 characters.

If you just want to count how many words fits that criterion, just do this:

```py
from pathlib import Path

sowpods = Path('sowpods.txt')

with sowpods.open() as f:
    words = f.read()
    counter = len([word for word in words.split() if len(word) > 14])
    print(counter)
```

Finally, if you don't care about readability, you can also do it as a one-liner, with no other modules dependency:

```py
print(len([w for w in open('sowpods.txt').read().split() if len(w) > 14]))
```

And here is a proof of concept:

```py
from pathlib import Path
from collections import Counter

sowpods = Path('zen-of-python.txt')

with sowpods.open() as f:
    words = f.read()
    counter = Counter([word for word in words.split() if len(word) >= 14])
    print(counter)

Counter({'implementation': 2})
```

Comment: Your answer is indeed valid but `Counter` is a bit of an overkill for this problem imo.

Comment: Not really. Anyway it is just an alternative and, if used the right way, a lot more flexible.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, don't mean to bash on alternative answers -- simply stating that the module `Counter` offers no obvious benefit in this case. Your use of `print(counter)` could've been substituted for `len(lst)` had you done `lst = [word for word in words.split() if len(word) >= 14]` beforehand. In other words, `Counter` didn't serve any benefit, so a bit overkill.

Comment: I didn't get you wrong and I know it could be a lot simpler (see my one-liner). My intention was to be more didactic and Pythonic.

Comment: I understand the sentiment on being didactic, but I don't understand how the extra import is more Pythonic. Whichever the case -- like we've been saying -- alternatives are always a positive :)

Comment: @FelipeFaria although this looks like a rather long-winded answer, this is the right one. Using standard imports and list comprehension you can quickly get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Let's fix your code together.

### `sowpods.txt`

```
HelloWorld
lolman
heyyo
okaylol
VeryLongWordProbMoreThan14Char
```

### `main.py`

If we run the first few lines of your code notice its output:

```py
b = open("sowpods.txt")
text = b.read()
text.strip("\n")
print(text)
```

outputs:

```
HelloWorld
lolman
heyyo
okaylol
VeryLongWordProbMoreThan14Char
```

Which seems to indicate the `text.strip("\n")` is not working. Well, looking up documentation on [`str.strip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) seems to tell us that it "**return[s] a copy of the string** with the leading and trailing characters removed," which means this is not the method you are looking for. Furthermore, it does not change the string *in place*, you would need to re-assign as follow: `text = text.strip("\n")`

Looking a bit further in the docs you might notice [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split), which seems to split the string based on some delimiter string... Let us give that a try:

```py
b = open("sowpods.txt")
text = b.read()
text_split = text.split("\n") # Notice we are setting this equal to a new variable.
print(text_split)
```

outputs:

```
['HelloWorld', 'lolman', 'heyyo', 'okaylol', 'VeryLongWordProbMoreThan14Char', '']
```

From here, I think things become a little bit more obvious then. Let's iterate through our list and using a simple `if-statement` print and count out any word that has a length greater than 14:

```py
b = open("sowpods.txt")
text = b.read()
text_split = text.split("\n")

count = 0
for word in text_split:
    if len(word) >= 14:
        count += 1
        print(word, "has size greater than 14!")

print("Count of word with len greater than 14 is", count)
```

outputs:

```
VeryLongWordProbMoreThan14Char has size greater than 14!
Count of word with len greater than 14 is 1
```

### Sidenote

Looking at your code as it is, it isn't terribly wrong.. but there are a few things that are broken:

```py
b = open("sowpods.txt")
text = b.read()
text.strip("\n") # HERE

i = 0
for row in text:
    n = len(row)
    while(n > 14): # HERE
        i += 1
print(i)
```

The first `HERE` was detailed above, and the second I'm going to expand on it now. Notice that the `while` loop you've declared technically never reaches an ending point.

```py
n = len(row)
while(n > 14): # HERE
    i += 1
```

That is, the variable `n` never actually decreases to the point that it is less than or equal to `14` (opposite of `x > y` is `x <= y`), and therefore the loop never ends. Furthermore, why bother with the `while` loop if your only intention is to increment `i` by **one** when `n > 14`? Easier to utilize a simple `if` statement:

```py
n = len(row)
if n > 14:
    i += 1
```

Hopefully, that helps!

---

For fun here is a simple one-liner using list-comprehension that will hopefully peak your interest with Python:

```py
print(len([i for i in open("sowpods.txt").read().split("\n") if len(i) > 14]))
```

outputs:

```
1
```

Comment: My pleasure. Make sure to click the arrow next to the answer that best answered your question so that the rest of the forum knows the author found an appropriate answer -- keeps the forum clean! :)

Comment: Better use just ```split()``` than ```split('\n')```. The first will make your could work also for lines with multiple words separated by any blank character.

Comment: I agree to both -- added "\n" to be more obvious, but you are indeed right. My preference was to actually use [`str.splitlines()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines) at first, but I figure I would generalize and use the more conventional `str.split()` method.

Comment: Damn corrector... that ```could``` was supposed to be ```code```. Sorry.

Answer (score -1):

Keep it short and pythonic:

```py
b = open("sowpods.txt")
text = b.read()

words = text.replace("\n", " ").split(" ")
long_words = [word for word in words if len(word) > 14]

print(len(long_words))
```

Comment: Thanks for the reference @accdias! I fixed my spacing in my answer.